# Is there a good way to get feedback on a potentially crackpot physics idea?

Tags: soft-question

I have a set of physics ideas that are probably false (they amount to a theory of everything, for a given value of theory), but at this point they are beyond my ability to evaluate.  I think there is a promising thread in the line of thought involved, and believe that some of the perspectives might be useful even if the ideas themselves turn out to be false, but I don't actually know what the next step would be; it is difficult to get somebody to look at a probably crankish idea.

I have looked into publishing a series of thought experiments, but rapidly ran into a wall there - arXiv requires somebody recommend me to publish to, for example, and I have the same issue there as with getting somebody to look at the ideas in the first place.

So what does a layman do in this situation?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a question about physics

Comment: Sincere answer: don't do anything. You'd be wasting everybody's time. Have fun and enjoy yourself with ToE's and thought experiments as much as you want. But don't try to share your results. The odds they are in any way useful are null.

Comment: Chat to physicists. Ask their opinion. You can do this [in our chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71/the-h-bar) but you will need a reputation of at least 20 to post there. Answer a few questions on conventional physics here to boost your rep - only two upvotes are needed to get a rep > 20.

Comment: Or vixra. There's always vixra.

Comment: Props for wanting to do the right thing. I'm upvoting this post to help you get the 20 rep needed for following through John's suggestion.

Comment: *"So what does a layman do in this situation?"* - become something other than a layman, i.e., commit yourself to studying the relevant physics and math so that you can evaluate your own ideas.

Comment: I'll look into answering some questions, thanks.  I don't know if that is appropriate either, but I'll ask before I launch into nonsense.

Comment: Learn enough physics so you don't feel the need to prefix your ideas with "I'm a layman" and "crackpot idea". Truly learn the subject matter and if you still feel you have a positive contribution try to move forward.

Comment: here are some general guides. If your idea contains math and allows for computation of results that predict outcomes, you can call it physics. if it does not, it is philosophy. if physics, then determine which branch it might belong in (cosmology, thermodynamics, electricity & magnetism, etc.) and get recommendations on standard expository texts of that field and familiarize yourself as thoroughly as you can with its historical development and the current state of the art. this will furnish a starting point for evaluating the possible validity of your ideas. good luck to you.

Comment: what niels said. It is physics if a mathematical model supports the ideas. From the time of Newton on mathematics is the sine qua non of physics, the language of physics. If you have a mathematical model vixra.org accepts off the beaten track papers, also hand waving ones I think.